# Model error with beego

Tags: go, orm, model, beego

I'm quite new on beego. I start a little project to discover and start to learn
the framework. I used the bee command to create the project:

```
bee new my_project
```

The version of beego is:

```
bee   :1.4.1
beego :1.6.1
Go    :go version go1.6.3 linux/amd64
```

I have a little model, the content of my model file is:

```
package models

import "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"

type ShortUrl struct {
    Id     int `orm:"auto"`
    Domain string
    Short  string
}

func init() {
    orm.RegisterModel(new(ShortUrl))
}
```

In the main file:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
    _ "github.com/hobbestigrou/mahewinsexyurl/routers"
)

func init() {
    orm.RegisterDriver("sqlite3", orm.DRSqlite)
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "sqlite3", "data.db")
    orm.RunCommand()
}

func main() {
    beego.Run()
}
```

In the controller file:

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"
    "github.com/hobbestigrou/mahewinsexyurl/models"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "github.com/ventu-io/go-shortid"
    "net/url"
)

type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

type Domain struct {
    Id  int    `form:"-"`
    Url string `form:"url"`
}

func (c *MainController) Get() {
    _ = beego.ReadFromRequest(&c.Controller)

    c.Data["Form"] = &Domain{}
    c.TplName = "index.tpl"
}

func (c *MainController) Post() {
    o := orm.NewOrm()

    flash := beego.NewFlash()
    domain := c.Input().Get("url")

    if _, err := url.ParseRequestURI(domain); err != nil {
        flash.Error("Please put a valid url")
        flash.Store(&c.Controller)
        c.Redirect("/", 302)
    }

    short, _ := shortid.Generate()
    ur := &models.ShortUrl{
        Domain: domain,
        Short:  short,
    }

    if created, _, err := o.ReadOrCreate(&ur, "Domain"); err != nil {
        if created {
            flash.Notice("The url was added: ", short)
            flash.Store(&c.Controller)
            c.Redirect("/", 302)
            } else {
                flash.Notice("The url already exists", short)
                flash.Store(&c.Controller)
                c.Redirect("/", 302)
            }
        }

        c.TplName = "index.tpl"
}
```

I know I can refactor the flash part but it's a detail at the moment.

The router:

```
package routers

import (
    "github.com/hobbestigrou/mahewinsexyurl/controllers"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
)

func init() {
    beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{})
}
```

I used the syncdb to create the table:

```
./mahewinsexyurl orm syncdb
```

The table was successfully created. But when I try to post data, I got an
error:

```
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:854][C] the request url is  /
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:855][C] Handler crashed with error <Ormer> table: `.` not found, maybe not RegisterModel
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:472
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/panic.go:443
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /home/hobbestigrou/go/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/orm/orm.go:110
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /home/hobbestigrou/go/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/orm/orm.go:135
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /home/hobbestigrou/go/src/github.com/hobbestigrou/mahewinsexyurl/controllers/default.go:47
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /home/hobbestigrou/go/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/router.go:763
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:2081
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/net/http/server.go:1472
2016/08/05 17:16:24 [router.go:861][C] /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998
```

What is my mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my error it was a careless mistake in the controllers:

```
ur := &models.ShortUrl{
    Domain: domain,
    Short:  short,
}

if created, _, err := o.ReadOrCreate(&ur, "Domain"); err == nil {
}
```

Thew new version is:

```
ur := models.ShortUrl{
    Domain: domain,
    Short:  short,
}

if created, _, err := o.ReadOrCreate(&ur, "Domain"); err == nil {
}
```

The error is the double usage of & to work and create pointer to a ShortUrl struct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this in your controller. Telling which database to use. I went to this link: [Beego ORM](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md#driver)

```
o := orm.NewOrm()
o.Using("default")
dr = o.Driver()
fmt.Println(dr.Name() == "default") // true
fmt.Println(dr.Type() == orm.DRSqlite) // true
```

**Update Try**

Tell the syncdb which db to use in the command:

```
./mahewinsexyurl orm syncdb -db="default"
```

Comment: It's not necesary to call the Using function, because it's already call by the NewOrm function see https://github.com/astaxie/beego/tree/master/orm/orm.go so it's not the reason of the error.